# How to get the project of Authenticated User in Laravel 7x

Tags: laravel

I have a CRM Project to make, the problem is, when the other user created a project, 
the project will display in project forms of all the users. How can i get the project of Authenticated Users.

THIS IS MY CONTROLLER

```
  <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Leads;

class LeadsController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $arr['leads'] = Leads::all();
        return view('leads.index')->with($arr);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('leads.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request, Leads $leads)
    {
        $leads->Name = $request->Name;
        $leads->Email = $request->Email;
        $leads->Address = $request->Address;
        $leads->contactnumber1 = $request->contactnumber1;
        $leads->contactnumber2 = $request->contactnumber2;
        $leads->contactnumber3 = $request->contactnumber3;
        $leads->sourcelink = $request->sourcelink;
        $leads->prevpublisher = $request->prevpublisher;
        $leads->leadminer = $request->leadminer;
        $leads->remarks = $request->remarks;
        $leads->verifier = $request->verifier;
        $leads->consultant = $request->consultant;

        $leads->Save();
        return redirect('leads');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

THIS IS MY VIEW.

```
                <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Address</th>
                    <th>ContactNo.</th>
                    <th>ContactNo.</th>
                    <th>ContactNo.</th>
                    <th>SourceLink</th>
                    <th>PrevPublisher</th>
                    <th>Leadminer</th>
                    <th>Remarks</th>
                    <th>Verifier</th>
                    <th>Consultant</th>
                </tr>
                @foreach($leads as $l)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ $l->Name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $l->Email}}</td>
                    <td>{{ $l->Address }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $l->contactnumber1}}</td>
                    <td>{{ $l->contactnumber2 }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $l->contactnumber3 }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $l->sourcelink }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $l->prevpublisher }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $l->leadminer }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $l->verifier }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $l->consultant }}</td>
                    <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-info">Edit</a> <a href="" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a></td>
                </tr>
                @endforeach
            </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to restrict your `$leads` to only the ones from your authenticated user:

```
    $arr['leads'] = Leads::where('user_id', '=', Auth::id())->get();
```

Assuming your have a `user_id` column

Comment: is that user_id came from the table users, or from the table leads?
I'm sorry for asking, its my first time using laravel.